# Count running total in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to make a query, which shows the progress of the number of users on my webpage by week.

I use following query to run the users database and get the number, grouped by a week:

```
SELECT TRUNC(FAB.LICENSE_DATE, 'IW'),
       COUNT(DISTINCT FAB.STATEMENT_NUMBER) AS "Number of account statements"
  FROM USERS FAB
 GROUP BY TRUNC(FAB.LAST_UPDATED_TIME, 'IW');
```

This gives following output:

```
 Date        |  Users
----------------------
 2015/09/07  |  5
 2015/09/14  |  4
 2015/09/21  |  6
```

But this is actually not what I want to achieve. I want to have the following output:

```
 Date        | Users
----------------------
 2015/09/07  | 5
 2015/09/14  | 9 (5 + 4)
 2015/09/21  | 15 (5 + 4 + 6)
```

How to modify the query so I get all the results?

Comment: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` - You are grouping by `TRUNC(FAB.LAST_UPDATED_TIME, 'IW')` but selecting `TRUNC(FAB.LICENSE_DATE, 'IW')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/000b02/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  LICENSE_DATE,
  LAST_UPDATED_TIME,
  STATEMENT_NUMBER
) AS
          SELECT DATE '2015-09-07', DATE '2015-09-07', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-08', DATE '2015-09-08', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-08', DATE '2015-09-08', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-09', DATE '2015-09-09', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-12', DATE '2015-09-12', 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-14', DATE '2015-09-15', 6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-15', DATE '2015-09-16', 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-16', DATE '2015-09-16', 8 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-17', DATE '2015-09-18', 9 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-21', DATE '2015-09-21', 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-21', DATE '2015-09-26', 11 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-22', DATE '2015-09-22', 12 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-23', DATE '2015-09-25', 13 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-24', DATE '2015-09-24', 14 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-27', DATE '2015-09-27', 15 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT LAST_UPDATED_WEEK,
       SUM( NUM_STATEMENTS ) OVER ( ORDER BY LAST_UPDATED_WEEK ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS "Number of account statements"
FROM (
  SELECT TRUNC(LAST_UPDATED_TIME, 'IW') AS LAST_UPDATED_WEEK,
         COUNT(DISTINCT STATEMENT_NUMBER) AS NUM_STATEMENTS
  FROM   USERS
  GROUP BY
         TRUNC( LAST_UPDATED_TIME, 'IW')
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/000b02/2/0)**:

```
|           LAST_UPDATED_WEEK | Number of account statements |
|-----------------------------|------------------------------|
| September, 07 2015 00:00:00 |                            5 |
| September, 14 2015 00:00:00 |                            9 |
| September, 21 2015 00:00:00 |                           15 |
```

Comment: this is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TRUNC(FAB.LICENSE_DATE, 'IW'), 
SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT FAB.STATEMENT_NUMBER)) OVER (ORDER BY  TRUNC(FAB.LAST_UPDATED_TIME, 'IW')) as "Number of account statements"
FROM USERS FAB
GROUP BY TRUNC(FAB.LAST_UPDATED_TIME, 'IW');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block for your problem :

`select u.date
      ,(select sum(u1.users)
          from users u1
         where u1.ddate <= u.date) as users
  from users u;`

It gives this output :

`07.09.2015   5
14.09.2015   9
21.09.2015   15`

Good luck

Comment: Using a window function will be much more efficient

Comment: Maybe, you can give a function example

Comment: All other answers use window functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello you can try this code too.

WITH t1 AS
  ( SELECT to_date('01/01/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') rn, 5 usrs FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('02/01/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') rn, 4 usrs FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('03/01/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') rn, 8 usrs FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('04/01/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') rn, 2 usrs FROM dual
  )
SELECT rn,
  usrs,
  sum(usrs) over (order by rn ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cumm_usrs
FROM t1
GROUP BY rn,
  usrs;
```